# is it possible to create @id on a existing column in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, javabeans, hibernate-mapping

I have a column in table which contains duplicates. Can I assign @id annotation over a reference which maps to this column in hibernate?

Comment: Nothing stops you from doing the same in the code :) All you need to do is clear that bogus data from the DB. You can always run a migration for this and implement a strategy for that id field so that it doesn't generate any duplicates from now

Comment: That's right, but if i do intentionally put @id over a column that contains duplicate value, should it generate an exception?